# How do I combine a line and a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I have two shape paths and I want to combine them into a single path, but after trying all options in the pathfinder tab, I haven't achieved the desired result. All of them just delete the line.

Here're the shapes.

[image]

And these are their layers.

[image]

How do I combine them into a single path so that I could align, move and reshape it as if it were a continuous shape?

#### Edit 1

The expand button seems to be disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want 1 shape from these two you can Expand them and Unite them via Pathfinder

Second, you can just Group them - they will save the relations to each other

Third, you can Make Compound Path from these  shapes...

Fourth, you can use Shape Builder tool to unite them via shift-click-drag

Comment: I've updated my question, none of these seem to have any effect?

Comment: @MorganWilde expand the path before pathfinder

Comment: @MorganWilde as I explained, you can make a compound path: Object->Compound Path->Make